# Can we add LINQ where condition of method parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Below is my existing method using inside some condition

```
public List<MenuItem> getTopMenu(List<Role> Id)
{

 // here many lines code for checking id value
}
```

I am changing above method to check where condition inside method parameter like below but not working code

```
public List<MenuItem> getTopMenu(List<Role> Id.Where(r=>r.status=="Active"))
{

}
```

Error is coming i need to pass only active id inside method i can not write individually to every method.

Comment: My confusion here: even if you could write a filter as part of the parameter, how is that different to writing it in the method itself?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Stop the method being called when the list has inactive items, or filter the list within the method?

Comment: every time one active id will apears with inactive id, please suggest how to achieve. @John

Comment: Again: what's stopping you doing this in the method?

Comment: How can we write inside mehtod?. @John

Comment: See Tarik's answer...

Comment: Method declaration and signature are a special place. Where those instruction have no place. Because of semantic and logic. What is the paramter do want to change the filter sometime to `r.status=="NoTActive"`? OR do you need to change the filter to `r.AnOtherProperty=="value"`? Or will you never change the filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the filter inside the method:

```
public List<MenuItem> getTopMenu(List<PersonRoleDTO> Id)
{
    Id = Id.Where(r=>r.status=="Active").ToList();
    // Whatever else
}
```

You cannot put statements as parameters to a method.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would better if you add the default parameter (`status="Active"`) on your method and use it like below.

- Also this makes your method more usable if you want to query with another status later.

```cs
public List<MenuItem> getTopMenu(List<PersonRoleDTO> Id, string status="Active")
{
   var query = Id.Where(r=>r.status==status); 
   
   //your logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is syntax and a design issue.
Syntax:

- You can't pass a condition as a parameter it doesn't make sense.

Design:

- You have multiple ways of doing this. My two suggestions are, either you can have a method to return the predicate to obtain only the active "Roles":

  private Func<Role, bool> OnlyActiveRoles(IList roles) => r => r.status == "Active";

  Or you can just filter the Roles list before calling those methods.

Comment: Nice addition to previous answers.